# How to use a custom font in Puppeteer running on an ubuntu server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts, puppeteer, digital-ocean

I am trying to push one of my projects to production on a digital ocean Ubuntu droplet. I installed `Source Sans Pro` as a font next to a default font that was already installed called 'dejavu'.

[image: installed fonts].

I already rebuild the cache with: `fc-cache -f -v`

When I run the command `fc-list`, I can cleary see that Source Sans Pro is installed (I assume):

[image]

After I cleared the cache I also restarted the app with `pm2 restart app.js` and `sudo service nginx restart` to make sure the changes had effect.

I use `Handlebar.js` and `Puppeteer` to generate an invoice. In that template I use the following code to use this custom font:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
      font-stretch: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Anyway, when I generate the invoice, for some reason the pre-installed font is the one that gets rendered:

[image]

What do I need to do to use `SourceSansPro` instead of the already installed `dejavu` font?